# Hierarchy implementation in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, hierarchical-data, angular-ui-tree

I'm new to angularjs and want to implement some `hierarchy` screen in which user can add a new group, child to that group and so on. (parent/child hierarchy)

Something like this

> 1 Admin
>
> 1.1 -----User Admin
>
> 1.1.1 ----------Tech Support Admin
>
> 1.1.1.1 --------------------Tech Support Team
>
> 1.2 ----------Login Admin
>
> 1.2.1 --------------------Profiles
>
> 1.3 -----Client Admin
>
> 1.3.1 ----------Client 1
>
> 1.3.2 ----------Client 2
>
> 2 Users
>
> 2.1 -----User 1
>
> 2.2 -----User 2
>
> 2.3 -----User 3

I've searched some tutorials and the only solution I found out relative to my problem is [angular ui tree](https://github.com/angular-ui-tree/angular-ui-tree).

But I'm not satisfied with that because I have to add images/avatar with all nodes (parents/children), then have to assign some roles to each of them on the basis of their parent node. but `ui-tree` does not have any procedure to add customized nodes or child of any node.

Is there any better approach to do this? Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: _"ui-tree does not have any procedure to add customized nodes or child of any node"_  I don't understand your concerns. You can design the nodes however you like them to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Long time.. let me post my solution here..may be it helps someone else..

So basically I did this with the help of [angular-ui-tree](https://github.com/angular-ui-tree/angular-ui-tree) with some custom changes to add avatar and links etc. here is html code;

```
<div class="panel-body">
     <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div ui-tree id="tree-root" ng-if="data.length > 0" data-drop-enabled="false" data-drag-enabled="false" data-nodrop-enabled="true">
           <ol ui-tree-nodes ng-model="data">
              <li ng-repeat="node in data" ui-tree-node ng-include="'nodes_renderer.html'" ></li>
           </ol>
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
```

and this is my script;

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="nodes_renderer.html">

 <div ui-tree-handle class="tree-node tree-node-content">

   <a class="btn btn-success btn-xs" ng-if="node.nodes && node.nodes.length > 0" data-nodrag ng-click="toggle(this)"><span
   class="glyphicon"
   ng-class="{
     'glyphicon-chevron-right': collapsed,
     'glyphicon-chevron-down': !collapsed
   }"></span></a>

   <a class="btn btn-xs" data-nodrag>
       <img ng-src="{{node.image}}" class="img-avatar" alt="Avatar" height="35" width="35"></a>
   {{node.title}}


   <div class="dropdown pull-right ">
       <a class="btn btn-primary btn-xs dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-nodrag><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list"></span></a>
       <div class="dropdown-content dropdown-menu" data-nodrag>
           <a ng-show = "flagCreateUserHierarchy" ng-click="btnAddUserClick(this)"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> Add User</a>
           <a ng-show = "flagUpdateUserHierarchy" ng-click="btnEditClick(this)"><i class="fa fa-folder-open"></i> Edit</a>
           <a ng-show="{{node.type}} <2 && flagUpdateUserHierarchy" ng-click="btnEditGroupClick(this)"><i class="fa fa-folder-open"></i> Edit Group Name</a>
           <a ng-show = "flagUpdateUserHierarchy" ng-click="btnDeleteHierarchy(this)"><i class="fa fa-ban"></i> Delete</a>
       </div>
   </div>
```

and this is how it looks like...

[image]

I can further explain this whole procedure if anyone needs to understand.

Answer (score 2):

To implement following structure there is property name **$parentNodesScope** added to get parent index so i added 

                    `{{this.$parentNodesScope.$parentNodesScope.$index+1}}.
                    {{this.$parentNodesScope.$index+1}}.
                    {{$index+1}} {{node.title}}`

1 Admin

1.1 -----User Admin

1.1.1 ----------Tech Support Admin

1.1.1.1 --------------------Tech Support Team

1.2 ----------Login Admin

1.2.1 --------------------Profiles

1.3 -----Client Admin

1.3.1 ----------Client 1

1.3.2 ----------Client 2

2 Users

2.1 -----User 1

2.2 -----User 2

2.3 -----User 3

Here is my jsfiddle link
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/arvindpal/ncL3gn1s/)

Answer (score 1):

I rolled my own solution on something similar.  I can't remember why I didn't go with ui-tree.  What I needed was a way to recursively create views so that I could mimic a filesystem.  [Here's the plunk from when I was proofing it out.](http://plnkr.co/edit/dYs3G3KWkOUcVbqmaNL3?p=preview)  This should be simpler for you since you're not trying to split files and folders like I did.

With the recursion helper I was able to declare my data structure like this:

```
$scope.items = [
  new File('item1', '/item1', 11, false),
  new File('item2', '/item2', 22, true),
  new File('item3', '/item3', 33, false),
  new File('A Really Long File Name Should Go Here', '/item4', 44, false),
  new Folder('Folder 1', '/folder1', [new File('item5', '/item5', 55, false)], false)
];
```

And I could render it using this:

```
<table class="table table-condensed table-responsive">
<tbody>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Size</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="item in getFiles()">
      <td class="minWidth4px">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.isSelected" />
      </td>
      <td class="truncateName">
        {{item.name}}
      </td>
      <td class="minWidth4px">{{item.size}}mb</td>
      <td ng-show="item.canPreview()" class="minWidth4px">
        <button class="btn" ng-click="openPreview(item)">Preview</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="item in getFolders()" ng-click="openFolder(item)">
      <td class="minWidth4px">
        <i ng-show="item.isOpen" class="fa fa-folder-open-o"></i>
        <i ng-hide="item.isOpen" class="fa fa-folder-o"></i>
      </td>
      <td colspan="3">
        <label>{{item.name}}</label>
        <attachments ng-show="item.isOpen" items="item.items"></attachments>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

And here's the directive for the attachements:

```
var attachmentsLink = function($scope) {
  $scope.openFolder = function(folder) {
    folder.isOpen = !folder.isOpen;
    console.log(folder);
  };

  $scope.getFiles = function() {
    return $scope.items.filter(function(x) {
      return x instanceof File;
    });
  };

  $scope.getFolders = function() {
    return $scope.items.filter(function(x) {
      return x instanceof Folder;
    });
  };
};

var attachmentsController = function($scope, previewService){
  $scope.openPreview = function(file) {
    previewService.preview = file;
    previewService.showPreview = true;
  };
};

var attachments = function(RecursionHelper) {
  return {
    compile: function(element) {
      return RecursionHelper.compile(element, attachmentsLink);
    },
    controller: attachmentsController,
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      items:'=',
    },
    templateUrl: 'attachments.html'
  };
};

angular.module("app").directive("attachments", attachments);
```

I can't take credit for the recursion helper that is the meat of it.  The recursion helper is [here](https://github.com/marklagendijk/angular-recursion)  Hope this helps.